# QJsonDocument to object is empty

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qjsonobject, qjsondocument

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON data in Qt5.

Code looks like this :

```
    ...
    socket->readDatagram(Buffer.data(),Buffer.size(),&sender,&senderPort);

    QJsonParseError jsonError;
    QJsonDocument dataJson = QJsonDocument::fromJson(Buffer.data(),&jsonError);
    if (jsonError.error != QJsonParseError::NoError){
        qDebug() << jsonError.errorString();
    }
    QJsonObject map = dataJson.object();
    //map["x"].toDouble()
```

But for some reason my map is empty, here is a debugging snap :
[image: QJsonDocument to object is empty]

How can I resolve this ?

Data :

```
'{\"x\":1,\"y\":2,\"z\":3}'
```

Comment: You should see your log print about json error string in application output of Qt Creator because fromJson call clearly doesn't succeed. And if parsing fails you shouldn't continue execution of your function but e.g. return from it. I suspect your json string escaping goes wrong. What if you replace single quotes with double quotes in your echo call?

Comment: I've test your piece of code and it worked for me! Make sure that your buffer is full when JSON deserializer start to work. Don't rely on debug outputs, add some console print and check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're reading correctly, you should test with a command like this:

`echo -n \{\"x\":1,\"y\":2,\"\z\":3\} > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8080`

So, get rid of single quotes and escape curly brackets.

Even better: put your json data in a `myfile` file and use `cat myfile > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8080`

Comment: this worked, but can you give me some reason how it worked ?

Comment: nothing really wrong in your code, more a bash issue, I think

Comment: Just one question, why sending data to `192.168.0.108` doesn't work?

Comment: It depends on how you bind (and on the address being correct). Try `udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::Any, 8080);` or `udpSocket.bind(8080);`, which is the same.

Comment: I've tried `Any`, `AnyIPv4`, hard-coded `192.168.0.108` everything, but doesn't work

Comment: I think you can post a new question about that (if you're super sure that the address is correct). Just post the `ip address` output in the question, possibly not as an image :) and maybe post enough code to have a Minimal, Reproducible Example, just to avoid downvotes.

Comment: actually i did, 5 hours ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232467/send-data-to-qt-applicationlaptop-from-android-using-udp

Comment: Are you reading from the `readyRead` slot? I think you should really post more code.